# 'find' is not able to find the file, what could be the reason?

Tags: linux

I could see a file is present in the location when I do `ls`, but when I do `find` on that file, it doesn't show; under what circumstance it might happen? Thanks.

```
[mega@bhlinapps]$ ls build_framework/scripts/CommonBuildScripts/itr_build.pl
build_framework/scripts/CommonBuildScripts/itr_build.pl
[mega@bhlinapps]$ find . -name itr_build.pl
[mega@bhlinapps]$
```

Comment: can you find any file ? using find command ? or just that one is causing problem

Comment: I didn't tried for all files, but yes I tried couple of files, it's not able to find

Answer (score 0):

```
fly@fly-desktop:~/Documents$ ls py/faces/face_landmarks.csv 
py/faces/face_landmarks.csv
fly@fly-desktop:~/Documents$ find . -name faces_landmarks.csv
fly@fly-desktop:~/Documents$
```

I did achieve your result.

i wrote a function named `find` in the terminal

```
fly@fly-desktop:~/Documents$ find(){ a=2
> }
```

then find will not call the as you expect. Probably you wrote a function called `find` in your `~/.bashrc` file which has the same name as `find`

Comment: no, there are no such thing in my bashrc. Also this happens with only this file/(or) the files under build_framework/scripts/CommonBuildScripts. If I search in just to the sibling directory of build_framework, i am able to find. [mega@bhlinBuild]$ find . -name buildLast.pl
./bin/buildLast.pl